# Monitoring transactions on a private blockchain

Tags: transactions, transfer, private-blockchain, performance

I just started working with EOSIO and I created a private blockchain with 4 producersfollowing the bios boot sequence tutorial (https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/tutorials/bios-boot-sequence).

**My goal is to heavy-load test the network and measure the average throughput (transactions per second) and latency for a bunch of token transfers.**

What's more, I will probably attempt to increase the number of producers and see how the results vary. I've achieved this on other platforms by sending the transactions and listening for transfer events.

I was wondering if there is something similar in EOSIO or what would be the right way to go about this task?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you could measure this, for example:

1. Send 1 EOS per transfer to an account with zero EOS, and measure how much EOS is in the account at the end of your test
2. Look at the nodeos logs to see how many transactions happened per block
3. Measure how many successful transfers were sent using scripting such as `bash`.
4. Create a plugin that monitors successful action traces and write the output to a database (may actually impact benchmark speed)